# How to store the results in table?

Tags: postgresql, rdbms

I have a one table A and that contains values

```
NAME     AGE
Loga     18
Anitha   20
Saranya  13
```

I was test the table values like if condition using case statement  case when AGE>=18 then 'major'
 else 'minor' then the results is

```
NAME     AGE  CASE
Loga     18  'major'  
Anitha   20  'major'
Saranya  13  'minor'
```

I want to add CASE and values of the results permanent in my A table. wheather its possible?

Answer (score 2):

```
alter table a add column new_column_name text;

update a
set new_column_name = case when age >= 18 then 'major' else 'minor' end
```

Comment: That update statement is unnecessarily complex - you just want `new_column_name = case when age >= 18 then 'major' else 'minor' end`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first add the column as NULLable using [ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html), then populate it for all existing values; you will probably then want to set it non-nullable:

```
ALTER TABLE a ADD COLUMN new_column text NULL;
UPDATE a SET new_column = CASE WHEN age >= 18 THEN 'major' ELSE 'minor' END;
ALTER TABLE a ALTER COLUMN new_column SET NOT NULL;
```

This will populate the initial values, and make it compulsory to populate the column for new values, but will not reflect any changes (so you will be able to update `age` to over 18, but leave the label as `'minor'`).

If the relationship between `age` and the new column should always hold, you might want to look into something more complex:

- a check constraint forcing all rows to match the condition
- a trigger automatically updating the new column when the age is inserted or changed
- using a view or function to capture the `'major'`/`'minor'` logic in one place, but not storing it redundantly on the table itself

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? Question is tagged PostgreSQL, and this is the most efficient way of achieving the same result as other answers have suggested. I have also now added some notes on further things to consider.

Comment: I've long given up wondering about drive-by downvotes. Just ignore 'em if they don't explain.

Comment: Ah, my bad, seems `USING` can't be used like that after all; maybe that's why the downvote. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I didn't down vote but `using` in that context is a syntax error. It looks like it can only be used in the `set data type` action.

Comment: Well, if it was @loganaayahee than that'd be darn bad manners but they don't have any rep -2's on this question so I'd say random. Still - testing suggestions is a good idea ;-) .  BTW please don't add an explicit `NULL` to nullable columns, it's non-standard and bad style.

Comment: Yeah, I could've sworn I'd used that exact syntax recently, so was pretty sure it would work, but I guess I was changing data types not adding columns.